# Assign subsequent html content to a php variable

Tags: php

Is it possible to declare a variable value like or something similar:

```
<?php
    $var =
?>

<!-- block of html code that goes into $var -->

<?php
    //do anything with $var that contains the html code of above
?>
```

Comment: Answer is yes, you can use. But before ask, you could easily check with `echo $var;` at second part of php!

Comment: But I'm getting `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '?> ' in index.php on line 8`.

Comment: You're looking for either a [heredoc](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc) or [nowdoc](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.nowdoc).

Comment: This error not about using `$var`, it is about your opening closing php tags. If you want to use `$var` inside of html,not php, you should write `<?php echo $var; ?>` inside of html after declaring of $var.

Comment: I don't think you understand my question. I'm trying to declare a variable, and set the value of that variable to the HTML content outside of the PHP block. So I have to use the closing php tags for that But it gives me an error.

Comment: @KidDiamond how is php supposed to know where that html content ends? The error you mentioned shows that this is not possible that way, better read a separate html file into the variable with `file_get_contents` or something like that. Code between `<php?` and `?>` is understood by the parser to be php, code outside that is not.

Comment: That's was the answer I was looking for for my question. So it is not possible to declare a variable like that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<?php
ob_start();
?>
<!-- block of html code that goes into $var -->
<?php
$var = ob_get_contents();
while (@ob_end_flush());
```

Note this assumes you are not already using output buffering.

Answer (score 0):

**No this is not possible.**

You can declare a variable in a `php`-block, then have that block terminate then some `html` part and then another `php` block and use it there.

But you cannot declare a variable like this, assigning the subsequent html contents to it.

But what you can do, as pointed out in [Anders J's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22963710/2186023) you can do the opposite, assign preceding contents to a variable. But note that there are some [possible pitfalls](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ob-start.php).

*Php is parsed by identifying the `<?php` `?>` block first, everything outside of that is ignored by the parser, so in order to do this you would better have that html content in a separate file and read it into your variable using something like `file_get_contents`.*